# Lilypond: Alternate, compound time signatures in parentheses

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to typeset this time signature from a hand-written manuscript:

[image: target]

A straight-up 7/8 time signature is easy

```
\time 7/8
```

[image: easy78]

The 2/4+3/8 is tougher but still not bad

```
\compoundMeter #'((2 4) (3 8))
```

[image]

A 7/8 signature in parentheses also seems reasonable:

```
\once \override Staff.TimeSignature.stencil = #(lambda (grob)
    (parenthesize-stencil (ly:time-signature::print grob) 0.1 0.4 0.4 0.1)
  )
\time 7/8
```

[image]

But when I apply that parentheses to the compound signature, things start to break-down (I get the 7/8 signature again)

```
\once \override Staff.TimeSignature.stencil = #(lambda (grob)
    (parenthesize-stencil (ly:time-signature::print grob) 0.1 0.4 0.4 0.1)
  )
\compoundMeter #'((2 4) (3 8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that ´compoundMeter` changes the time signature stencil to

```
#(lambda (grob)
  (grob-interpret-markup grob (make-compound-meter-markup args)))
```

You override this to use the original stencil. So you simply need to combine these:

```
hybridCompoundMeter =
#(define-music-function (args) (pair?)
   #{
     \compoundMeter #args
     \once \override Timing.TimeSignature.stencil =
     #(lambda (grob)
        (let ((stc1 (ly:time-signature::print grob))
              (stc2 (parenthesize-stencil
                     (grob-interpret-markup grob (make-compound-meter-markup args))
                     0.1 0.4 0.4 0.1)))
          (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge stc1 X RIGHT stc2 0.8)))
   #})

{
  \hybridCompoundMeter #'((2 4) (3 8))
  8 8 8 8 8 8 8
}
```

which then looks like this:

[image]

Comment: That is super useful info.  How did you know that?  Is this in an scm/ file thay you could grep, in the notation reference, or did you happen you know off the top of your head?  Either way.  I love it, but I'd like to know how to answer this myself in the future.

Comment: Oh, and I love how easily you've demonstrated how much better this solution is with the 4+3 groups of eighths

Comment: @Stewart The beat structure is in fact handled by the compoundMeter command. When I read your description I already suspected that compoundMeter changes the stencil callback, I then simply looked up the definition in `ly/music-functions-init.ly`. Generally you’ll find a lot in `ly/` (for Lilypond code) and in `scm/` (for schema code).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that just marks-up the whole thing:

```
\once \override Staff.TimeSignature.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
\once \override Staff.TimeSignature.text =
  \markup {
    \override #'(baseline-skip . 0)
    \center-column \number { 7 8 }
    \raise #-1.25 { \fontsize #5 { "(" } }
    \override #'(baseline-skip . 0)
    \center-column \number { 2 4 }
    \raise #-1 { \fontsize #5 { "+" } }
    \override #'(baseline-skip . 0)
    \center-column \number { 3 8 }
    \raise #-1.25 { \fontsize #5 { ")" } }
  }
\time 7/8
```

[image]

Not sure if that's the best method, especially since the parentheses take up a lot of horizontal space (unlike the beautiful parentheses provided by `parenthesize-stencil`).

I can live with this, but I'm interested if there's a prettier solution out there (with the nicer parentheses)